# Two divergence questions

Tags: calculus

[image]I have these two questions and I think I've done the first one correctly. I don't know how to do the second one and also how to draw target curves. I'd really appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine, you are taking a course on electromagnetism and trying to calculate the electric field of a (pure) electric dipole [part a] and magnetic field of a (pure) magnetic dipole [part b]. The calculation of these two is actually tricky if you want to also know the behavior at $r=0$ too. The precise result (for both) involves Dirac delta functions.

The tricky part of the calculation is finding the red part in the following:
$$
\boxed{
-\nabla\left(\frac{\vec{p}\cdot \vec{r}}{r^3}\right)=
3\frac{(\vec{p}\cdot \vec{r})\vec{r}}{r^5}-\frac{\vec{p}}{r^3}
\color{red}{-\frac{\vec{p}}{3}\: 4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})}
}
$$
Note that the red part only contributes to the result at $r=0$ and nowhere else. I'm sure you are expected to derive this Dirac delta function in your exercise. The black part of the right hand side is however not difficult to calculate (I'll leave it to you, and by the way the answer is definitely not zero!).

For part (b) maybe first prove the following: Let $\vec{A}, \vec{B}$ be two vector fields then
$$
\nabla \times (\vec{A}\times \vec{B}) =\vec{A}(\nabla\cdot \vec{B})+(\vec{B}\cdot \nabla)\vec{A}-
\vec{B}(\nabla\cdot \vec{A})-(\vec{A}\cdot \nabla)\vec{B}
$$
Then if $\vec{A}=\vec{m}$ is a constant, and $\vec{B}=\vec{r}/r^3$, using the above relations we have (I'll leave it to you)
$$
\nabla (\vec{m}\cdot\vec{B})=(\vec{m}\cdot \nabla)\vec{B}
$$
and
$$\nabla \times (\vec{m}\times \vec{B})=\vec{m}(\nabla \cdot \vec{B})-
\nabla (\vec{m}\cdot\vec{B})
$$
Using these you will find that
$$
\boxed{
\nabla\times \left(\frac{\vec{m}\times \vec{r}}{r^3}\right)=3\frac{(\vec{m}\cdot \vec{r})\vec{r}}{r^5}-\frac{\vec{m}}{r^3}\color{red}{+\frac{2\vec{m}}{3}\: 4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})}}
$$
Again I'm sure your instructor does not expect you to find the Delta function (red) part and the black part should be enough. Other than the behavior at $r=0$ the electric field of electric dipole and magnetic field of magnetic dipole are completely analoguos.

Finally for the tangent curves, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#/media/File:Magnetic_dipole_moment.jpg) for inspiration.